# Why does "\n" display different when entered on stdin instead of from code?

Tags: c++, c

Suppose I have an array of characters `char str[10]`.

If I store the value `xyz\nabc` in `str` using `char str[10]="xyz\nabc";` and output it, it gives the following output:

```
xyz
abc
```

On the other hand, if I give it input from `stdin` in the form `xyz\nabc` and then print it, it gives the following output:

```
 xyz\nabc
```

Why is it so?

Answer (score 7):

When you read it from `stdin`, you get exactly the string `"xyz\nabc"`, as it appears.

If you hard-code that value in the code (i.e. `char* x = "xyz\nabc"`), the `\n` is a single character, and it represents a new line. To get the same output, you need `char* x = "xyz\\nabc"` - the extra `\` escapes the `\`.

See this http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape

Comment: what is the reason behind it ?

Comment: @code_hacker because you don't read escape characters from stdin. :)

Comment: For example, we've developed a grammar where the dollar sign is the "escape character", so "$N" is like C++ "\n" (yes, "$$" is a single dollar sign).  Although we program in C++, stdin does not know our (not even C++) escape sequence rules.  stdin just sees \ or $ as those specific characters.